# Can a linux user set their proxy so that the settings cannot be seen from either history or env?

Tags: linux, rhel, proxy

Bear with me here as I do not know why my company setup our Linux system this way but...

What they want us to do is to log into the remote server using our personal id/password but then immediately sudo over to another account. Everyone will be required to sudo over to this same account after logging in, let's just call this account "developer".

So we each login and then: sudo su - developer

My concern is that if I now set my proxy settings as usual by exporting them then anyone and everyone using the developer account will be able to see my proxy settings which include my personal userid and password. I also am unable to set the proxy in my .bashrc as it is now essentially a shared file...

Is there any other way that I can set my proxy without exposing my credentials to everyone else who is sharing this developer account?

Comment: Multiple users `sudo su`ing to one developer account is a Red Flag.  Update your resume and start looking. It's a sign of lazy SDE design, and will, as it has in the past, lead to disaster. Who will be blamed when `developer` blunders? The level of ignorance, both of how Software Development is done, and of Linux System Administration makes me worry about a disaster-in-progress. Run away!

Comment: Other "users" can still see your proxy credentials via environment variables.